# SpringSecurity　ログイン機能　formで変遷する時に必ずfailureUrlに飛ばされてしまう

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Springでログイン機能の実装を行っています。
以下の記事を参考にしました。

[Spring-Bootでログイン機能を実装してみる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/a-pompom/items/80b3f4bb6414e8678829)

段階を踏んで実装を行っていて、formからsubmitした際に値の判定を行わずに、ただ他の画面に変遷するような機能をまず実装していました。

formで値を入力して、successForwardUrlで対象のURL（hello）に飛んで欲しいのですが、上手くいきません。
login?errorの画面にいってしまいます。

記述に何か不備があるのでしょうか？

どなたか分かる方がいれば、よろしくお願いします。

#### フォルダ構成

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### ソースコード

**list.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="~{layout/component :: head('ログイン')}">
<body>
<th:block th:replace="~{layout/component :: header}"></th:block>
<div class="container">
    <th:block th:replace="~{layout/component :: container_top('ログイン')}"></th:block>
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <form method="post" th:action="@{/sign_in}">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>ログインID</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="username">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>パスワード</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="submit" value="確認" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<footer th:replace="~{layout/component :: footer}"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```java
package com.example.demo.login;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    //フォームの値と比較するDBから取得したパスワードは暗号化されているのでフォームの値も暗号化するために利用
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                            "/images/**",
                            "/css/**",
                            "/javascript/**"
                            );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login") //ログインページはコントローラを経由しないのでViewNameとの紐付けが必要
                .loginProcessingUrl("/sign_in") //フォームのSubmitURL、このURLへリクエストが送られると認証処理が実行される
                .usernameParameter("username") //リクエストパラメータのname属性を明示
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successForwardUrl("/hello")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

**MvcConfig.java**

```java
package com.example.demo.login;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /**
     * 「/login」というURLからlogin.htmlを呼び出す
     */
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/328940) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

リンク先の実装をどこまでされているか分かりませんが、質問文中のコードだけで判断すると、エンコーダ指定を行っているのが間違っています(ので常に認証失敗します)。

デフォルトでは `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` 形式([参考](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.5/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe-format))で保持されているので、下記を削除する必要があります。

```java
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
```

リンク先のコードでは [この辺り](https://github.com/a-pompom/spring-boot-login_app_demo/blob/6ead60a0bd22226622cb39422aff6e2bcb6ce4e6/src/main/java/login/app/config/WebSecurityConfig.java#L83) で手当しています(がQiita記事中では触れられていないようです)。

---

該当Qiita記事は他者が読んでわかりやすい記事とは思いませんので、別のサンプルコードを探された方が良いかと思います。